# Query mongodb array of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've a bunch of documents that look like:

```
{
   "ids": [{"name":"aa", "age":1}, {"name":"bb", "age":2}]
}
```

I'd like to be able to query my documents providing a collection of ids, something like

```
db.getCollection('Collection').find({"ids":{$in : [{"name":"aa", "age":1}, {"name":"bb", "age":2}]}})
```

Generally that works, however it breaks when the fields order is changed, so for example I cannot find documents when I execute the following query

```
db.getCollection('Collection').find({"ids":{$in : [{"age":1,"name":"aa"}, { "age":2, "name":"bb"}]}})
```

I know that I could try to always execute a query with fields "in order", but from my current task perspective it's not always possible. Any help with that ?

Comment: can you please explain why we can't process the request to make it in the sorted form before making a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) when you want to run your query against an array of objects:

```
db.col.find({ $or: [ { "ids": { $elemMatch: {"age":1,"name":"aa"} } }, { "ids": { $elemMatch: { "age":2, "name":"bb"} } } ] })
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K3G0rmhjsTB)

EDIT: you can decide whether `$or` or `$and` should be a top level operator (depending on your use case)

Comment: yeah, the problem is I've tried a similar approach with $or, and it turned out that the performance is quite bad. That's why I've experimented with $in, which gave better performance, however it turned out to fail when the order of fields have changed

Comment: @macpak that's because the way they work is different. $in checks exact matching while $elemMatch is a set of rules that are applied on each element - that's why order makes no difference